# How to write PowerShell output to a file as a table instead of a list?

Tags: powershell

How to write PowerShell output to a file as a table instead of a list ?

I am an absolute beginner to PowerShell, and having hard time getting this done, would appreciate any help on this.

I am using PowerShell script to export some fields as a table to a file, but I am getting the output as a list in the csv file instead.

Here's my script:

```
[string]$workspacesPath = "D:\Users\xxxx\Documents\MyFolder\TestWSUs.csv"

$emptyworkspaces = Import-Csv -path $workspacesPath 

foreach ($workspace in $emptyworkspaces) {

    $userlist = ((Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups/$($workspace.workspaceId)/users" -Method Get) | ConvertFrom-Json).value
    $result = $userlist | ForEach-Object {
        $CurrentObject = $_
        $GetUserEmail = ($CurrentObject.emailAddress)
        $GetUserAccessRight = ($CurrentObject.groupUserAccessRight)
        $GetUserDisplayName = ($CurrentObject.displayName)
        $GetUserPrincipalType = ($CurrentObject.principalType)
        $GetworkspaceId = ($workspace.workspaceId)
        $GetworkspaceId
        $GetUserEmail 
        $GetUserAccessRight 
        $GetUserDisplayName 
        $GetUserPrincipalType
       } 
        $result | Out-File "D:\Users\xxxx\Documents\MyFolder\Output\testmar292.csv" -Append
       
}
```

The output that I see in csv file is as below:
[image: CurrentOutput]

I'm hoping to get the output like seen in this image:
[image: Expected Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct 1 object per row you want in the CSV file, then pipe sais objects to `Export-Csv`:

```
$workspacesPath = "D:\Users\xxxx\Documents\MyFolder\TestWSUs.csv"

$emptyworkspaces = Import-Csv -LiteralPath $workspacesPath 

$emptyworkspaces |ForEach-Object {
    $workspace = $_
    $userlist = ((Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups/$($workspace.workspaceId)/users" -Method Get) | ConvertFrom-Json).value
    $userlist | ForEach-Object {
        # create 1 object = 1 row, per group member
        [pscustomobject]@{
            WorkspaceID = $workspace.workspaceId
            Email = $_.emailAddress
            AccessRight = $_.groupUserAccessRight
            DisplayName = $_.displayName
            PrincipalType = $_.principalType
        }
    } 
} |Export-Csv -LiteralPath "D:\Users\xxxx\Documents\MyFolder\Output\testmar292.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Format-List is the wrong format for csv files.  Format-Table would be another wrong format.  What you want is Export-Csv.
Try this(you may still have some debugging ahead of you):

```
$userlist = ((Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups/$($workspace.workspaceId)/users" -Method Get) | ConvertFrom-Json).value
$result = $userlist | ForEach-Object {
    $CurrentObject = $_
    $GetUserEmail = ($CurrentObject.emailAddress)
    $GetUserAccessRight = ($CurrentObject.groupUserAccessRight)
    $GetUserDisplayName = ($CurrentObject.displayName)
    $GetUserPrincipalType = ($CurrentObject.principalType)
    $GetworkspaceId = ($workspace.workspaceId)
    $GetworkspaceId
    $GetUserEmail 
    $GetUserAccessRight 
    $GetUserDisplayName 
    $GetUserPrincipalType
   } 
    $result | 
     Export-Csv "D:\Users\xxxx\Documents\MyFolder\Output\testmar292.csv" -Append
```

Comment: Piping string values to `Export-Csv` will result in a file with a single column containing the `Length` property values of each string

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help, I've already tried export-csv but it was giving the length of the string as a single column instead of the values.